# Return the name of the post type

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, custom-post-type-archives

I have this in the archive.php file of my theme:

```
<?php else : ?>
  <h1 class="archive-title"><?php printf( __( get_post_type() ) ); ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And it returns the slug for the post type. I'd like it to return the plural name of the post type instead. What should I use to replace get_post_type()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
<h1 class="archive-title">
  <?php echo get_post_type_object( get_post_type() )->label; ?>
</h1>
```

Comment: Great if you can solve your own problem. +1 for that, and also posting your solution. Don't forget to accept your own answer.